# Documents are removed from MongoDb but sh.getShardDistribution() command still shows chunks available on each shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding, chunks

I removed all documents from my collection as

```
mongos> db.myCollectioName.remove({});
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 88517 })
mongos>
```

But when i ran the following command it showed me **chunks:5** for each shard

```
mongos> db.myCollectioName.getShardDistribution();

Shard shard0 at shard0/some_ip1:some_port,some_ip2:some_port,some_ip3:some_port

data : 0B docs : 0 chunks : 5
estimated data per chunk : 0B
estimated docs per chunk : 0

Shard shard1 at shard1/some_ip1:some_port,some_ip3:some_port,some_ip3:some_port
data : 0B docs : 0 chunks : 5
estimated data per chunk : 0B
estimated docs per chunk : 0

Totals
data : 0B docs : 0 chunks : 10
Shard shard0 contains NaN% data, NaN% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : NaNGiB
Shard shard1 contains NaN% data, NaN% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : NaNGiB
```

Does that mean they are empty chunks?

And is it like next time when i insert document in same collection   it will  use the same chunk    configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means there are empty chunks. The chunks (which are ranges of shard key values or hashes of shard key values) remain what they were before you deleted the documents. If you reinsert documents, they will be put on the shard that holds the chunk containing the value of the (hash of the) shard key value. MongoDB doesn't merge chunks automatically. All this information is as of MongoDB 2.6. The method of dealing with empty chunks could change in the future.

The MongoDB Manual contains instructions on manually [merging chunks](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/merge-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/).